# Ways to end at the same vertex on triangle

Tags: combinatorics

I know how to start the problem, which is by finding the easy cases. If the bunny alternates between two vertexes, it would land back on the same vertex. This works with both vertexes, that is 2 cases. There are many more ways and I don’t know how to find them without listing them out. Can I have some help?

Comment: Tag this question as homework. I have the exact same homework, and this question is from AoPS homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a comparatively brute force approach that relies on gathering data for smaller numbers of jumps, spotting a fairly evident pattern, and proving that the pattern continues indefinitely.

Let $n_A(k)$ be the number of ways for Bunbury to end at vertex $A$ after $k$ jumps, $n_P(k)$ the number of ways for him to end at vertex $P$ after $k$ jumps, and $n_S(k)$ the number of ways for him to end at vertex $S$ after $k$ jumps.

- Show that $n_P(k)=n_S(k)$.
- Show that $n_A(k+1)=n_P(k)+n_S(k)=2n_P(k)$.
- Show that $n_P(k+1)=n_A(k)+n_S(k)=n_A(k)+n_P(k)$.

Since each jump can always be made to either of $2$ vertices, there are $2^k$ $k$-jump paths, i.e., $n_A(k)+n_P(k)+n_S(k)=2^k$. Make a table showing $n_A(k)$, $n_P(k)$, $n_S(k)$, and $2^k$ for small values of $k$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
k&n_A(k)&n_P(k)&n_S(k)&2^k\\\hline
1&0&1&1&2\\
2&2&1&1&4\\
3&2&3&3&8\\
4&6&5&5&16\\
5&10&11&11&32
\end{array}$$

The table suggests the conjecture that

$$n_A(k)=\begin{cases}
\frac13(2^k-2),\text{ if }k\text{ is odd}\\
\frac13(2^k+2),\text{ if }k\text{ is even}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$n_P(k)=n_S(k)=\begin{cases}
\frac13(2^k+1),\text{ if }k\text{ is odd}\\
\frac13(2^k-1),\text{ if }k\text{ is even}.
\end{cases}$$

This conjecture can be proved by induction on $k$.

Comment: @MathNoob: No, not at all. By definition it is $n_A(10)$.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Count each step as $+1$ or $-1$ and count the ways in which the sum of the ten moves can be divisible by $3$. Since the total is even, it must in fact be divisible by $6$. There are $\binom{10}k$ ways to reach a total of $10-2k$. So which of these binomial coefficients do you need to add up?